Is there any information on how many Eldar usually live on an Exodite world?
While there is some information on the wiki such as them eschewing technology and being nomadic (making me think that their population is around tens of millions) I could not find anything that says "There are usually between X and Y amount of Eldar on an Exodite planet."
Are there any references to how many Eldar there are in an average Exodite world?
Context
I have recently started GM'ing a Rogue Trader game and among the endeavor prompts I gave my players, the one that most intrigued them was helping evacuate an Exodite planet and finding them a new home as the planet is on the path of a tyranid fleet and none of the craftworlds or other planets are willing to render aid.

I couldn't find precise info either BUT we can make some educated guesses based on the available information
Like.. For example tens of millions is likely too high, they live a more "natural" life than their Craftworld kin, they still possess advanced Eldar physiology and a long lifespan. This, combined with the limited resources of even a relatively pristine planet, suggests their populations would be carefully managed and unlikely to reach the tens of millions. But thousands to hundreds of thousands is more plausible. This  seems more in line with their described nomadic lifestyle and the carrying capacity of a pre-industrial society, even one with advanced agricultural techniques. This also fits with the idea that they live in scattered, relatively small communities across the planet.
Now.. For your Rogue Trader game.. You have considerable freedom to determine the population of the Exodite world in question. Think about this
--- The urgency of the evacuation. A smaller population will be easier to evacuate, while a larger one will create a more dramatic and challenging scenario for your players.
--- The resources available to the players. The size of the population will impact the logistical challenges of the evacuation, such as the number of transports required and the availability of supplies.
--- Yuour story. Do you want the focus to be on a desperate race against time to save a small, vulnerable community, or a massive undertaking with significant political and logistical implications?
You could even tie the population size to the players' actions! Perhaps initial scouting missions reveal a smaller population than expected, but later discoveries uncover hidden settlements, increasing the scale of the evacuation. How bout that?

Earth has surpassed 100 mil people around 2500 years ago. Pre-industrial society can easily reach tens of milions of beings. Especially as the main issues that prevented population growth on Earth would be absent in Eldar population - lack of food and lack of medical knowledge. Planets are after all quite huge
